# Gameobject's position is different between unity and iPhone (5)

Tags: c#, iphone, unity-game-engine, 2d, gameobject

I'm making a simple 2D game in Unity. The gameobject's position is different from Unity editor to my iPhone. For example, if I want to place a gameobject in the center, then I need to place it a little further up before it is in the center on my iPhone. And i'm using iPhone 5 resolution in unity. Hope you guys can help or explain why this happen.

Comment: What game object, exactly, are you referring to? Is it a UI object? If it is, what are it's RectTransform properties, and what are the properties of the active canvas? What are the properties of the camera?

Comment: @MaxYankov I'm sorry I'm new with Unity so I'm not familiar with these setting... Yes, it is all UI objects and only them. Can i take a screen dumb of anything so you can help?

Answer (score 0):

Check the offsets of parents of the game object. It's possible that the outtermost object isn't set to be at `0,0`.

Otherwise we're probably going to need to have more information to help you. Screenshots or code snippets or something.

Comment: Thanks for your respons @justin.m.chase. It is only my UI objects that don't fit. And i can't change the position of the canvas